# Fix my VB.NET code using Collections which breaks when ported to UWP project

Tags: vb.net, porting, uwp

Fix my VB.NET code using Collections which breaks when ported to UWP project.

In my legacy VB desktop program I have code using Collections like this:

```
Private myCollection As New Collection
...<then some lines later>...
myCollection.Add(myObject1, CStr(KeyValue))
...<then also some lines later>...
myCollection.Add(myObject2)
```

That code is targeted to .NET 3.5 and it works fine, since according to the manual I learned from, the Collection class overloads the Item property to take a string as a key.

BUT, when ported to a project targeted to Universal Windows Build 10240, that code produces flags with errors "Too few type arguments to Collection(Of T)". To fix that, I have re-factored my code as follows:

```
Private myCollection_D As New Dictionary(Of String, myObject1)
Private myCollection_C As New Collection(Of myObject2)
...<then those later lines become>...
myCollection_D.Add(CStr(KeyValue), myObject1)
...<talso these later lines become>...
myCollection_C.Add(myObject2)
```

Is this the best (only) way to fix this? I have hundreds of errors through out my project which will need hand coded changes.

Is there any documentation covering porting VB.net to UWP that would alert me to these problems?

Comment: `Collection` is a VB collection storing objects (only).  `Collection(Of T)` is something else to store typed objects

Comment: What happens when you replace `New Collection` with `New Microsoft.VisualBasic.Collection`?

Comment: If the original `Collection` is `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Collection`, then it looks like that type [may not be available](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt185497.aspx) for UWP apps.

Comment: Type 'Microsoft.VisualBasic.Collection' is not defined is what happens

Comment: The original is "Imports System.Collections.Generic"